# Chrome iPhone 6 emulator 100% width is wider than device

Tags: html, css, iphone, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have an element `app` which sits inside `body`.

`app` has a width of `100%`, however when I view the page with the iPhone 6 emulator in Chrome I see that the `app` element is much wider than the viewwport (causing an overflow).

`38%` width is the width at which all of the element is inside the viewport.

Notice that on `100%` width you cannot see the right edge of the inputs:

[image: 100% width]

On `38%` width however you can:

[image: 38% width]

I have the following meta tag in my HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only happens when the width is applied through the element inspector. I will log an issue with Chrome.

Comment: getting the same problem, can you post a link to the issue if you logged it.